# Django: How to have a local Postgresql connection when production postgres database is on heroku?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

My production postgresql database is successfully running on Heroku. Before this, I had a local postgres database configured as the default during development. But, now, after I hooked the Heroku postgres with `dj-database-url`, whenever I run `python manage.py runserver` to make changes locally, I get this error:

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required
```

This is my database setting:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'DATABASE_URL': os.getenv('DATABASE_URL'),
        'NAME': os.getenv('DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DATABASE_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('DATABASE_PORT')
    }
}
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=True)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

Even though not required, my local `DATABASE_URL` in `env` is this:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database name}?sslmode=require
```

It only worked i.e. `runserver` ran successfully when I commented the `dj-database-url` snippet but that's not a solution.

So, how do I run a local Postgres database along with the Heroku postgres?

Comment: You could separate the settings for each environment like in [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-harden-your-production-django-project).

Comment: Thanks, produced a working version with that article. One vital thing is, I must add `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` -> `<app_name>.settings.production` in Heroku config vars. Otherwise, `heroku run... makemigrations` and `migrate` will throw unimaginable errors.